# Error variable no definida Javascript parámetros a partir de una Url,¿Cómo solucionarlo?

Tags: javascript, condiciones, url

Estoy obteniendo parametros de in link para abrir un modal, al momento de imprimir mis parametros funciona pero el modal no abre por el if, ya intenté poner le código dentro del mismo bloque de javascript pero no trabaja. el Url desde el que estoy trayendo parámetros es el siguiente http://seth.com/dashboard?ftime=0

este es el código:

```
<script>


window.onload = function() {
            try {
                var url_string = (window.location.href).toLowerCase();
                var url = new URL(url_string);
                var ftime = url.searchParams.get("ftime");
                console.log(ftime);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("nomodals" + err);
            }
}

      if(ftime == 0){
        $(window).on('load', function(){
          setTimeout(function(){
            $('#completdetails').modal('show')
            }, 1);
      })};

    </script>
```

También hice pruebas sin el if y el modal sí abre, también quisiera agregar que el modal no se cierre haciendo click fuera, pero no se exáctamente cómo se hace eso con Js

Para el modal estoy utilizando bootstrap4

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onload = function() {
    try {
        var url_string = 'http://seth.com/dashboard?ftime=0';
        //var url_string = (window.location.href).toLowerCase();
        var url = new URL(url_string);
        var ftime = url.searchParams.get("ftime");
        console.log(ftime);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("nomodals" + err);
    }
    if(ftime == 0){
        setTimeout(function(){
            alert('abrir modal');
            //$('#completdetails').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
        }, 1);
    }
};
```

Dentro del `if` tienes esta linea `$(window).on('load', function(){`, es algo contradictorio porque indicas que se ejecute cuando la pagina este cargada.

Así que lo incluí en el `window.onload`.

> A manera de prueba asigne `var url_string = 'http://seth.com/dashboard?ftime=0';` directamente y comente la linea original. Ademas que en lugar de abrir un modal coloque un `alert`

Con este comando `$('#completdetails').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});` se indica lo siguiente:

1. `backdrop: 'static'`: no se cierra el modal al hacer clic.
2. `keyboard: false`: no se cierra el modal al presionar una tecla `ESC` por ej.

Mas info:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#options

Comment: Buenísimo, ya veo dónde tenía que agregar los elementos, muchísimas gracias @Cesar

Answer (score 0):

Estaba utilizando algo que se llama Closure, por lo que eliminé el functión y seguía trayendo la variable.

```
<script>



                var url_string = (window.location.href).toLowerCase();
                var url = new URL(url_string);
                var ftime = url.searchParams.get("ftime");


      if(ftime == 0){
        $(window).on('load', function(){
          setTimeout(function(){
            $('#completdetails').modal('show')
            }, 1);
      })};

</script>
```